# Test a system running with Database

Tags: database, testing

This is question about testing a system running with database.
Many systems will work back in database,
How do you test it?
In each case, it is dependent on database,
It seems that the information fitting is not really easy. Total size of database is more than tens of tera bytes.
Our system also has about 700 tables and many transactions, so it is not easy to test.

If you have any knowhow, please share it.

Comment: create a backup? or insert the data into a test database

Comment: what is database are you using ? mongodb or what ?

Comment: We are using oracle, and when testing, we use flashback function of oracle, and that is a huge load and time.

Comment: Instead of working with TBs of data, you might split your data. You have the DDL part, which gives you the schema (tables, views, users ...). Then you need a *certain* amount of transaction records to test workflows. Don't try to test on a whole prod dump. Either invest the time for new test data, or grab some part of the dump and don't forget to anonymize it.